# How to insert rows into columns from another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, worksheet-function

I'm trying to prefill a template with repeating data in a column like this: 
Sheet1:

```
A1
Offer Name:
Offer URL:
Network:
Payout $:
Share%:

Offer Name:
Offer URL:
Network:
Payout $:
Share%:

...
```

What I'd love to do is insert data from Sheet2, which is in a row: Sheet2:

```
A1      B1      C1          D1  E1
name1   link1   network1    1   5%
name2   link2   network2    1   5%
```

and have that prepopulate Sheet1 like this:

```
A1          B1
Offer Name: name1
Offer URL:  link1
Network:    network1
Payout $:   1
Share%:     5%

Offer Name: name2
Offer URL:  link2
Network:    network2
Payout $:   1
Share%:     5%
```

So I could drag the filler down in the Sheet1 and have it prefill as much content as there is in Sheet2. I've tried concatenate, but formula doesn't work.

Is it possible to do with a formula?

Comment: Paste-special transpose will get you close, but if you want exactly what you described you'll need a little VBA.  If you're open to using it (VBA), then the task should be no big deal.

Comment: yeah thanx I'm trying to avoid scripts if possible, so i could have something simpler in the future to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Sheet1 starts in A1 with `Offer Name:` and `name1` is in Sheet2 A1 please try in Sheet1 B1 copied down to suit:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!A$1,INT(ROW()/6),MOD(ROW()-1,6))
```

You might series fill Sheet1 ColumnA by selecting A1:A12 and dragging the fill handle down to suit. If desired to remove the `0` from B6, B12 etc. then filter ColumnA to select `(Blanks)` and delete the zeros. Also use filter if required to format the percentages.

Comment: pnuts this is amazing, thanx. I couldn't figure it out. It really works. Just one thing, is is possible to have blank cell inserted when copying instead of 0 value in every 6th row?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in love in keeping your Sheet1 ordered vertically while still listing your fields vertical as well you're going to have to make some allowances. Like Hambone suggested this would be more rigorously done in VBA. If you still prefer to just use formulas here is a potential solution. For each row item in Sheet1 you would use the following formula:

```
="Offer Name: "&Sheet2!A1&CHAR(10)&"Offer URL: "&Sheet2!B1&CHAR(10)&"Network: "&Sheet2!C1&CHAR(10)&"Payout $: "&Sheet2!D1&CHAR(10)&"Share%: "&Sheet2!E1
```

The implication is that this will display all the fields for each item in 1 cell with forced carriage returns in between them. This allows you to be able to drag your formula down and capture for all items. You have to set your cells to wrap text to be able to view correctly. Hope this helps. Regards,